# Find max value of an arraylist of objects

Tags: java, arraylist, max

let say I already have a class called Motorbike, in there there's a `getWeight()`
I don't know why my code doesn't work, this is for a test and I don't have the sample texts

```
public static ArrayList<Motorbike> maxWeight (ArrayList<Motorbike> motorbikes){
    ArrayList<Motorbike> max_list = new ArrayList<Motorbike>();
    Motorbike max = motorbikes.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < motorbikes.size(); i++){
        if (motorbikes.get(i).getWeight() > max.getWeight(){
            max = motorbikes(get(i));
            max_list.add(max);
        }
    }
    return max_list;
}
```

This is the Motorbike class:

```
public class Motorbike
{
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String manu;
    private int quantity;
    private double price;
    private double weight;
    private String date;
    
    public Motorbike(String id,String name,String manu,int quantity,double price,double weight,String date){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.manu = manu;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.price = price;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.date = date;
    }
    
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getManu(){
        return manu;
    }
    public int getQuantity(){
        return quantity;
    }
    public double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
    public double getWeight(){
        return weight;
    }
    public String getDate(){
        return date;
    }
    
    void printMotorbike(){
        System.out.println(getId() + " " + getName() + " " + getManu() + " " + getQuantity() + " " + getPrice() + " " + getWeight() + " " + getDate());
    }
}
```

the error is `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`
I submitted my code so that's all I can give

Comment: 'Motorbike max = motorbikes.get(i);'  where is 'i' declared?

Comment: You want the ONE max motorbike regarding the weight ? The method shouldn't return a List

Comment: I fixed that part and the method is already written for us, we can only add our code to it

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, with the Motobike definition and sample code to test. Also epxlain HOW it doesn't do what you want

Comment: For future reference, when you post your next question on _stackoverflow_: If your [java] code is throwing an exception, post the entire stack trace and not just part of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The max is *one*, not a list, so forget using max_list.

Try using the [`max`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#max(java.util.Comparator)) method of a stream:

```
Motorbike max = motorbikes.stream()
  .max(comparing(Motorbike::getWeight))
  .orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Problems

- the error `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0` means that the provided `ArrayList<Motorbike> motorbikes` is **empty** so you may add a check on that before
- the max weighted motorbike is ONE motobike, so your method should return one element not a `List<Motorbike>`

#### Solution

With a for-loop, you may have something like

```
static Motorbike maxWeight(List<Motorbike> motorbikes) {
    if (motorbikes.isEmpty())
        return null;
    Motorbike max = motorbikes.get(0);
    for (Motorbike m : motorbikes) {
        if (m.getWeight() > max.getWeight()) {
            max = m;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```

Using Streams, you can have

```
static Motorbike maxWeight(List<Motorbike> motorbikes) {
    return motorbikes.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Motorbike::getWeight)).orElse(null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that more than one motorbike in the list may have the maximum weight and method `maxWeight` needs to return all the motorbikes that have the maximum weight.

First you need to find what that maximum weight is.

After you find the maximum weight, you need to again iterate through the list and extract all those motorbikes whose weight equals the maximum weight that you found.

Hence you need to iterate through the list twice.

```java
public static ArrayList<Motorbike> maxWeight(ArrayList<Motorbike> motorbikes){
    ArrayList<Motorbike> maxList = new ArrayList<Motorbike>();

    // Find maximum weight.
    Motorbike max = motorbikes.get(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < motorbikes.size(); i++){
        if (motorbikes.get(i).getWeight() > max.getWeight(){
            max = motorbikes.get(i);
        }
    }

    // Find all motorbikes in list having maximum weight.
    for (Motorbike bike : motorbikes) {
        if (bike.getWeight() == max.getWeight()) {
            maxList.add(bike);
        }
    }
    return maxList;
}
```